# Query.Add instead of Dynamic Component Loader (loadintolocation)

Tags: typescript, angular

I am using Dynamic Component Loader, the "loadIntoLocation" variant. But this is no longer available in latest versions of Angular2.

How to transform this code and get same functionality?

```
    this.dcl.loadIntoLocation(OpsComponent, this._el , "dynamicpanel").then((cmp)=>{
        this.compRef = cmp
        // input
        cmp.instance.forwarddata = { name: "teddy" }
        // output
        cmp.instance.emitter.subscribe(event=>{ console.log(event) })
        return cmp
    })
```

How to refactor this, keep functionality and use new Query.read instead?

**Breaking change notice:**

*core: add Query.read and remove DynamicComponentLoader.loadIntoLocation. (efbd446)*

*DynamicComponentLoader.loadIntoLocation`has been removed. Use`@ViewChild(‘myVar’, read: ViewContainerRef)`to get hold of a`ViewContainerRef`at an element with variable`myVar`.*

*DynamicComponentLoader.loadIntoLocation has been removed. Use @ViewChild(‘myVar’, read: ViewContainerRef) to get hold of a ViewContainerRef at an element with variable myVar. Then call DynamicComponentLoader.loadNextToLocation.
DynamicComponentLoader.loadNextToLocation now takes a ViewContainerRef instead of an ElementRef.*

FINAL SOLUTION

```
this.resolver.resolveComponent(ChildComponent).then((factory:ComponentFactory) => {
this.compRef = this.dynamicpanel.createComponent(factory)
// input
this.compRef.instance.forwarddata = { name: "Teddy"}
// output
this.compRef.instance.emitter.subscribe(event => {       this.onChildEvent(event) })
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a reference to [`ViewContainerRef`](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/core/ViewContainerRef-class.html) which is used as target. You can either inject it like

```
constructor(private viewContainerRef:ViewContainerRef) {}
```

or get it for an element in the view using `@ViewChild()`

```
<div #target></div>
```

```
@ViewChild('target', {read: ViewContainerRef}) target;
```

**ViewContainerRef.createComponent (>= beta.17)**

Inject the `ComponentResolver`

```
constructor(private resolver: ComponentResolver, 
    /* if required also 
    private viewContainerRef:ViewContainerRef */) {}
```

then add the component like

```
this.resolver.resolveComponent(this.type).then((factory:ComponentFactory<any>) => {
  this.cmpRef = this.target.createComponent(factory);
  // here you can set inputs and set up subscriptions to outputs
    // input
    this.cmpRef.instance.someInput = someValue;
    // output
    this.cmpRef.instance.someOutput.subscribe(event=>{ console.log(event) });
});
```

**DynamicComponentLoader.loadNextToLocation() deprecated (beta.17)**

then add the component like

```
this.dcl.loadNextToLocation(SomeComponent, this.target).then((cmpRef) => {
  this.cmpRef = cmpRef;
});
```

See also https://stackoverflow.com/a/36325468/217408 for a Plunker

Comment: We forgot to put in "input" and "output", very important ;) I added in my post

Comment: This part hasn't changed therefore I didn't bother. I updated my answer anyway. Thanks for pointing it out.