# viewComponentRef and component factory used for rendering controls in angular 2 reference

Tags: angular, custom-controls, eventemitter

I created some custom control and render a json of form attributes using the component factory and view resolver.

Same approach as below. 
[Query.Add instead of Dynamic Component Loader (loadintolocation)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37047530/query-add-instead-of-dynamic-component-loader-loadintolocation)

In custom controls I am emitting a `valueChanged` event. The problem is that the `viewcomponent` ref always points to the last control that was rendered. 
so in `this.valueChanged.emit(event)` code , "this" points to the last rendered control though the event emitted is of the control that has been changed.

How to overcome this ?

Comment: I can't make sense of that description. Can you please post the code that demonstrates what you try to accomplish. Ideally with a Plunkter that allows to reproduce.

Comment: HI, thanks for the comment. I was able to fix the issue. Using component ref i am adding custom built controls to a form. I was not able to get the handle of those controls on value changes. Now i am able to get it by adding listeners.